# How to set margin for a view based on condition - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I like to have margin set to TextView based on condition. I have declared values in dimens file that needs to be set based on condition.

```
<dimen name="tall">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="short">5dp</dimen>
```

In view xml, am trying to set the margin

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personal_bio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@{isTall ? @dimen/tall:@dimen/short}"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@{viewmodel.personalBio}"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But on compile, this throws error like `Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView android:layout_marginTop> that accepts parameter type 'float'`

Similar condition works fine for other properties like visibility, color and other few but couldn't get it working to set margin.

Is there any workaround available to achieve this in xml itself ?

Comment: in this case you can make a custom binding for this where you set you margin value dynmic

Answer (score 0):

try to use custom binding

```
class CustomBindings {
companion object {

    @BindingAdapter("setTopMargin")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setTopMargin(view: View, isTall : Boolean){
        getTopMargin(view as TextView,isTall )
    }

    private fun getTopMargin(textView: TextView, isTall : Boolean) {
      if(isTall){
        val typedValue = TypedValue()
        textView.context.resources.getValue(R.dimen.tall, typedValue, true)
        val tall= typedValue.float.toInt()
        
        val param = textView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        param.setMargins(0,  tall, 0, 0)
        textView.layoutParams = param
     }else{
        val typedValue = TypedValue()
        textView.context.resources.getValue(R.dimen.small, typedValue, true)
        val small= typedValue.float.toInt()
        
        val param = textView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        param.setMargins(0,  small, 0, 0)
        textView.layoutParams = param}
    }
    }

}
}
```

in xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/personal_bio"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
setTopMargin="@{isTall}"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@{viewmodel.personalBio}"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the value tall / small is always 0. Hence it doesn't make any impact on the layout.